# Yii Framework: Different view (on actionIndex) depending on user's role

Tags: php, yii

I'm a beginner in Yii Framework, and I have a problem I can't fix. I have this in my class controller :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Absence');
  $this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  ));
}
```

That gives me a list of all 'absence'.

In my case, 'erty' is logged in and sees a list of every absence. But, with his role, stored in my user's table, I want him to see only a list of absences with his 'Collaborateur alias'.
Can someone helps me with it ?

Comment: How do you manage your roles in your application? How are they attached to the user/session?

Comment: Hello, I have a column 'roles' in me table and a WebUser class. Thanks to that, I can used `Yii::app()->user->getState('roles')` to know and compare roles of logged in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('role', $user->role /* replace this with required role*/, true);
```

And attach it into DataProvider

```
 $dataProvider  = new CActiveDataProvider('Absence', array( 'criteria'=>$criteria));
```

Comment: Ok, thank you emte, I compare 'alias' instead of 'role' in my criteria, and it works !! Now I will try to put a IF statment to know if a user can see everybody, according to his role. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Better still, and as it's a business rule, it should go in the Absence data model.

So you can add a scope in your Absence data model:

```
'mine'=>array(
    'order'=>'a_sort_column DESC',
    'condition'=>'role=:role',
    'params'=>array(
        'owner'=>Yii::app()->user->getState('roles'),
               ),
        ),
```

and then in your code use

```
     $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider(Absence::model()->mine())
```

If its relevant you can always use a default scope if this filter is always applied.

If this filter is always applied except in an admin context, think about using another class that extends the Absence model and applies the default scope like

```
  class myAbsence extends Absence
  {
       public function defaultScope()  {

          return array(
    'order'=>'a_sort_column DESC',
    'condition'=>'role=:role',
    'params'=>array(
        'owner'=>Yii::app()->user->getState('roles'),
               ),
        );
   }
```

and then in your non-Admin controllers you would use

```
     $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('myAbsence')
```

Comment: emte's solution works, and I use it for all my project (9 tables/controllers/models...). And I have to test roles to know what logged in user can sees, and I have also to know if the Absences concerns him, but that's not necessarily this user that created this absence. I don't know if my english is clear, don't hesitate to ask me to reformulate. And I don't know about Scope, can you explain me a little more ?

Comment: Named Scopes are a way to define filters within the model.  The data model is where you should try and place all business logic and therefore, a better place to hold this kind of functionality. Also easier if you want to use it in different places.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that, if I have time I will rebuild this with Scope, it is certainly better to use it in my case. For now, it is working with emte's solution, but I think it doesn't really respect MVC architecture right ?